# Load a different stylesheet in WordPress if an admin is logged in

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to be able to put a conditional PHP code in my theme which loads a different stylesheet when an admin or just one user (ID=1) is logged in.

Is there a WordPress function to achieve this?

There's this div with a class (let's say "example") which is set to "display: none" on a post.

I just want admins to view it when they're logged in and I'll create a new CSS property for the class like:

```
.example {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a function for this in functions.php

```
function admin_stylesheet()
{
    if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {

        wp_register_style('admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('admin_css'); 

    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_stylesheet');
```

Answer (score 2):

I never used WP but if you can edit the code you could do a simple query if the admin is logged in and then use some inline-code

```
<div class="example" <?php if($admin == 1){ echo 'style="display: block;"';} else{ echo 'style="display: none;"'; ?>> CONTENT </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do three things:

1) Make sure you use the standard WordPress [body_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function in your template. This will add lots of helpful classes to the body element of your HTML.

2) Add a filter on body_class to add a new helper class to the body when the user is an admin user. For example, in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
// Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $classes[] = 'admin-user';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

3) Use this new class in your standard CSS stylesheet to override your default when on an admin page:

```
.admin-user .example {
    display: block;
}
```

This solution does things in a pretty standard, theme-friendly way, and avoids using either a separate stylesheet or an inline style.

Comment: And how do I add body_class to my template? I'm using Thesis 1.8 framework currently. Can I add <body <?php body_class($class); ?>>  in a hook and make it work?

Comment: It looks to me like Thesis has its own support for body classes, see [this example in the Thesis documentation](http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/filters/thesis_body_classes/). Basically, just use `thesis_body_classes` as the filter name in step 2, rather than `body_class`. You won't need step 1 as Thesis already supports body classes by default. (Take a look at the source of your  site with its Thesis theme and you should see a bunch of helpful classes on the `body` element already.)

Comment: Ah that's what it is. Thanks a lot mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can check that the current user is admin by following way

```
    <?php

    if(current_user_can( 'manage_options' ))

     {
     ... admin stuff....
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I believe [is_admin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) actually checks to see if the current page is in the administration area, rather than checking if the current user is an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like as follows

```
<?php 
     if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        ?>
        <style>
               .example {
                    display: block;
                }
        </style>
        <?php 
     } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is to add your admin stylesheet registration and enqueueing action to the `admin_head` hook,

```
function add_custom_stylesheets_admin() {
    $handle = '<HANDLE>';
    $src = '<PATH_TO_STYLESHEET>';
    wp_register_script($handle, $src);
    wp_enqueue_style($handle, $src, array(), null, null);
}
add_action('admin_head', 'add_custom_stylesheets_admin');
```